# Is a modded Yaesu FT-270r acceptable to use on MURS frequencies?

Tags: united-states, legal, vhf

I am a bit new to the radio scene, so excuse me for any ignorance that may follow.

I saw on a website that you could mod the Yaesu FT-270r so that you can increase its transmission range outside of 144 MHz. I have no plans on transmitting outside of  FCC designated MURS frequencies. (I am not a licensed ham operator.)

Would it be legal and/or OK to transmit on MURS with this mod on this radio? I'd rather find out know then start transmitting on MURS and get in trouble with the FCC for doing so if it is illegal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. I'm also not particularly familiar with MURS, and generalizing from other information.*

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Use_Radio_Service#Eligibility), MURS (as many other US unlicensed radio services do) requires the use of **type accepted** equipment.

(Terminology note: *radio services* are CB, FRS, GMRS, MURS, amateur, commercial, etc.)

This means that the only radios you can use on MURS are those which the FCC approves for use on MURS. So, no, your modded radio cannot legally be used. (Modified equipment is only useful on the amateur bands or otherwise on frequencies which *you have been granted a specific a license to use*.)

And in these services which require type-accepted equipment, FCC generally only approves equipment *which cannot be used for licensed services* — the widely understood rationale being that they don't want to trust the users of the type-accepted equipment not to use the other functions.

Thus, there is no radio which you can legally use in the US which allows transmitting on both amateur frequencies and unlicensed service frequencies.

Comment: What about say Anytone TERMN-8R? If I remember correctly, at one point they had certification for that radio for GMRS, MURS and had a radio that could work on amateur radio frequencies. Unfortunately, FCC's database seems to be down at the moment, so I can't check what's going on there now.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I _think_ I heard that that ended up being cancelled or limited or something. Not sure at all.

Comment: Yep, their request was dismissed. See: https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2568413